# Qt how to know the widget, in which elements user set focus last time

Tags: qt, qwidget, qevent

Qt. I have a form. There is 2 widgets on it, that contains other widgets, buttons, line edits etc.
I need: When user sets focus, clicks by mouse, or does something with first widget or elements, that it contain - I need to set variable to 0. If he do something same with second widget - variable must be set in 1.
How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QApplication::focusWidget()` returns pointer to widget which has focus at this moment. Also there is `QApplication::focusChanged(QWidget *old, QWidget *now)` signal and you can connect it to slot to change variable.

Comment: Thank you its really simple, and it works.
void FormBackupPower::application_focusChanged (QWidget*old, QWidget*now){
const QWidget *widget = now;
const QWidget *step1 = dynamic_cast<const QWidget*>(this->ui->groupBoxStep1);
const QWidget *step2 = dynamic_cast<const QWidget*>(this->ui->groupBoxStep2);
while (widget != NULL) {
    if (widget == step1) {
        this->setCurrentStep(FormBackupPower::currentStep_low);
        break;
    }
    if (widget == step2) {
        this->setCurrentStep(FormBackupPower::currentStep_low + 1);
        break;
    }
    widget = widget->parentWidget();
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can always redefine/(create subclasses by inheritance) the widgets with your own slots and signals.

As far as I can understand your requirement, you can do.

QObject::connect(wid1,SIGNAL(clicked()),yourvariableclass,SLOT(setMyVariable_wid1()));
QObject::connect(wid2,SIGNAL(clicked()),yourvariableclass,SLOT(setMyVariable_wid2()));

If my answer isn't apt for your question, please explain the problem a little more. I can help you with it. :)

Comment: I dont want to redefine each component. There is must be a more human way.

Comment: Then simply use the signal slot mechanism to connect the focus event of each widget to a slot which takes care of flipping the variable's value between 0 and 1. The syntax goes like what I've mentioned.

Comment: Also, its no where as difficult as you think to inherit a widget class. You just inherit a widget class, add new/custom signals and slots. In order to use it in the UI, you can add a normal widget and then promote it into your custom widget type.

But as far as I can see from your requirement, you can simply use the signal slot mechanism.